# How to stop opening a login page in (asp.net webforms) when user is already logged in the same browser in different tab

Tags: asp.net

I have logged in as a user and it works fine , but when i try to open the login in a different tab in same browser it still goes to the login.aspx without the actual member page

Please help !

Aboutus.aspx

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Session["Username"] == null)

        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");


        }
        else
        {
            string Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
            Label1.Text = Username;
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Login.aspx

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
    }



    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {



            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(*)FROM [dbo].[Reg] WHERE Username='" + Login1.UserName + "' and Password=@pass");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            ////create an array of bytes we will use to store the encrypted password
            Byte[] hashedBytes;
            ////Create a UTF8Encoding object we will use to convert our password string to a byte array
            UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();

            ////encrypt the password and store it in the hashedBytes byte array
            hashedBytes = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(Login1.Password));

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", hashedBytes);
        var username = Login1.UserName;
            int OBJ = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (OBJ > 0)
            {
            if (username == "admin")
            {
                Session["Username"] = Login1.UserName;
                Response.Redirect("AdminPanel.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Username"] = Login1.UserName;
                Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
            }
           }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Invalid username or password";
                this.Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: any idea about session?

Comment: Yes i did use sessions but when i write the if and else on page load in login.aspx   ..Let say if (Session["Username"] != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }

Comment: please go through this article here 'http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/how-to-make-a-login-form-using-session-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/'

Comment: did you debug? were you creating a session when user gets log in?

Comment: Yes i did and i am sending the session variable to the member page which is current about us page ...Session["Username"] = Login1.UserName;
                    Response.Redirect("About.aspx");

Comment: please debug your code! if session is null that means you are not saving the username in the session, and save the username on the time of login

Comment: can you provide the login method as well as your page load method on about.aspx? write that in your question Please!

Comment: how can you say the session is null , if i open the about us page(Member page) in different tab it works fine and display data of that particular user but when i open the login page without logging out..it goes to the login page not to the Members page in different tab( same browser )

Comment: Wait a min Please let me understand you first.... You are saying session is fine but you wish to redirect the page to Index page instead of login page if the session is not null? Right?

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear , please check code ..let me explain you again :  if a user is logged in( session running) , open a new tab in same browser and open login page ..it goes to the login page not the member page but the user is already logged ..i want to write condition in login.aspx to achieve this

Comment: If I understand what you said: can you place a same check on the login page of yours as you've placed it on about.aspx page , change you login page load method as according check if session is null do nothing if its not null redirect it to index page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Page_Load` of Login.aspx do this:

```
if(Session["Username"] != null)

    {
        string username = Convert.ToString(Session["Username"]);
        if (username == "admin")
            {

                Response.Redirect("AdminPanel.aspx");
            }
            else
            {

                Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
            }

    }
```

Comment: if the session is running and i try to access the login page in different tab same browser ? where will that go , just moves on to the next function which login authenticate..no need to write an else for if ( session not null) ..

Comment: you will be redirected to home page.

Comment: Home page itself is the Login page login.aspx...is there any need to write else statement for the if ( session not null) which you haven't added in your  code ...?

Comment: by home page i meant first page after login. No there is no need to add else statement

Answer (score 1):

Your page laod method on Loginpage must be like this

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["Username"] == null)

    {


    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx",false);
    }

}
```

I hope this helps